# Why didn't the Zoldyck teach Killua Nen

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Killua is the Zoldyck with the highest potential, why didn't his familly teach him Nen?

Even as a kid he would definitely be able to learn it, at least the basic principles.

Answer (score 4):

From the manga it emerges that they wanted to control him for as long as possible in order to grow him as a killer.
By teaching him the nen, thanks to his potential, he could have rebelled at any time, while, thanks to the fact that he did not know the nen, they were able to control it much longer.
Eventually they led him to identify himself as a killer. Basically a kind of brainwashing.
Not only that, his brother also used the nen to put a physical / psychological block directly into his brain.
And before he could get rid of it, Killua had to learn not only the basics of nen.
Moreover, the nen provides a sort of shortcut in protecting against lightning and torture. While his family wanted his body to adapt to these things regardless of the nen.
Obviously sooner or later they would teach him, also for this reason Killua's father let him go, he knew that, in any case, he would learn what he needed to be a killer.
In short, Killua was raised as a killer first of all from a psychological and physical point of view, learning the nen before all of this would have simply made Killua less strong and, consequently, less suitable to be a killer.